# How to extract data from HTML table column in Python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have a long list of table rows. The first three elements look like this.

```
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/compressed.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="wsp_120hr5km_latest.zip">wsp_120hr5km_latest.zip</a></td><td align="right">2020-11-19 21:24  </td><td align="right"> 15K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>

<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="latest_wsp64knt120hr_5km.kmz">latest_wsp64knt120hr..&gt;</a></td><td align="right">2020-11-19 21:24  </td><td align="right">715 </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>

<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="latest_wsp50knt120hr_5km.kmz">latest_wsp50knt120hr..&gt;</a></td><td align="right">2020-11-19 21:24  </td><td align="right">1.9K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

what would be the cleanest way to extract the href and the date/time from one of them.

So far I have the following

```
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(tbl_row[0])
print("parsed html",parsed_html)
```

It prints

```
parsed html <tr><td valign="top"><img alt="[   ]" src="/icons/compressed.gif"/></td><td><a href="2020111906_wsp_120hr5km.zip">2020111906_wsp_120hr..&gt;</a></td><td align="right">2020-11-19 09:24  </td><td align="right"> 17K</td><td> </td></tr>
```

Is there a way to extract href and the date/time from the parsed_html variable?

Comment: What have you tried so far, can you please show us your effort ?

Comment: i'll edit the question to show what I am trying.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
tbl_row = ['<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/compressed.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="wsp_120hrhalfDeg_latest.zip">wsp_120hrhalfDeg_lat..&gt;</a></td><td align="right">2020-11-19 21:24  </td><td align="right"> 14K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>', '<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/compressed.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="wsp_120hr5km_latest.zip">wsp_120hr5km_latest.zip</a></td><td align="right">2020-11-19 21:24  </td><td align="right"> 15K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>', '<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="latest_wsp64knt120hr_5km.kmz">latest_wsp64knt120hr..&gt;</a></td><td align="right">2020-11-19 21:24  </td><td align="right">715 </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>']


for i in tbl_row:
    parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(i)
    row_val = parsed_html.find_all('td')
    print(row_val[1].find('a')["href"],row_val[2].getText())
```

It prints

```
wsp_120hrhalfDeg_latest.zip 2020-11-19 21:24  
wsp_120hr5km_latest.zip 2020-11-19 21:24  
latest_wsp64knt120hr_5km.kmz 2020-11-19 21:24
```